# $Vld\left(\frac{X = X \cap Y}{X \subseteq Y}\right) true \ or false$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

$$Vld\left(\frac{X = X \cap Y}{X \subseteq Y}\right) true \ or false$$

My answer: True $$ \forall x((x \in X) \land (x \in Y) \Rightarrow (x \in Y)  $$

Feel free to critique my answer and/or add your own using a new method.

Comment: Yes it is true.  That useless tautology does not show for all x in X, x in Y.

Answer (score 1):

Better than what?  What if it is not a one liner?

Premise: X = X $\cap$ Y.  Conclusion: X $\subseteq$ Y.
Proof.  Assume x in X.  So x in X $\cap$ Y. Thus x in Y.
Thus for all x in X, x in Y, i.e. X $\subseteq$ Y.